# DirectX11 only draws half of the vertices in a populated index and vertex buffer

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, directx, direct3d

Im having an issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

Im importing obj files with TinyObjLoader, and copying vertex and index buffers to GPU memory to draw the model. There are *only triangles in this model. No 4+ sided polygons, and no negative indices*

The only problem is I cannot draw the full model, only 1/2 to 2/3 of the vertices are drawn, with correct vertices, correct normal, and correct textures.

I split the code in two methods with #defines to illustrate this issue.
Note, there is a heavy amount of trial and error that went into figuring this out to make it work, as there is a scarcity of tutorials and education online on DirectX11. If you see any issues with the way the code is structured please feel free to comment.

1. Method 1 is the failing code. Here I make duplicates of the vertices in order to have different normals. This is essential in my model because each surface needs a different shading.  Note:I understand I can make this rendering more optimized with std::unordered_map for some duplicate vertices where normals point in the same direction.

   ```
   #ifdef DUPVERTICES
   std::vector<float> vertex_buffer;
   std::vector<uint32_t> index_buffer;

   struct T_Vertex
   {
       float vX;
       float vY;
       float vZ;
       float nX;
       float nY;
       float nZ;
       float tX;
       float tY;
       uint32_t vXIndex;
       uint32_t vYIndex;
       uint32_t vZIndex;
       uint32_t nXIndex;
       uint32_t nYIndex;
       uint32_t nZIndex;
       uint32_t tXIndex;
       uint32_t tYIndex;
   };

   std::vector<T_Vertex> temp_vertices;
   size_t index_offset = 0;
   for (size_t f = 0; f < shapes[0].mesh.num_face_vertices.size(); f++) {
       int fv = shapes[0].mesh.num_face_vertices[f];
       // Loop over vertices in the face.
       for (size_t v = 0; v < fv; v++) {

           // access to vertex
           tinyobj::index_t idx = shapes[0].mesh.indices[index_offset + v];
           if (idx.vertex_index < 0 || idx.normal_index < 0 || idx.texcoord_index < 0)
               continue;
           T_Vertex temp_vertex;
           temp_vertex.vX = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 0] : 0;
           temp_vertex.vY = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 1] : 0;
           temp_vertex.vZ = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 2] : 0;
           temp_vertex.nX = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 0] : 0;
           temp_vertex.nY = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 1] : 0;
           temp_vertex.nZ = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 2] : 0;
           temp_vertex.tX = idx.texcoord_index > 0 ? attrib.texcoords[2 * idx.texcoord_index + 0] : 0;
           temp_vertex.tY = idx.texcoord_index > 0 ? attrib.texcoords[2 * idx.texcoord_index + 1] : 0;

           temp_vertex.vXIndex = 3 * idx.vertex_index + 0;
           temp_vertex.vYIndex = 3 * idx.vertex_index + 1;
           temp_vertex.vZIndex = 3 * idx.vertex_index + 2;
           temp_vertex.nXIndex = 3 * idx.normal_index + 0;
           temp_vertex.nYIndex = 3 * idx.normal_index + 1;
           temp_vertex.nZIndex = 3 * idx.normal_index + 2;
           temp_vertex.tXIndex = 2 * idx.texcoord_index + 0;
           temp_vertex.tYIndex = 2 * idx.texcoord_index + 1;
           temp_vertices.push_back(temp_vertex);
       }
       index_offset += fv;
   }

   for (auto& temp_vertex : temp_vertices)
   {
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vX);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vY);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vZ);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nX);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nY);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nZ);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.tX); //Set to 0 for no texture
       vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.tY); //Set to 0 for no texture
       vertex_buffer.push_back(0.0F);

       index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vXIndex);
       index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vYIndex);
       index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vZIndex);
       index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nXIndex);
       index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nYIndex);
       index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nZIndex);
       index_buffer.push_back(0);
       index_buffer.push_back(0);
       index_buffer.push_back(0);
   }
   ```
2. Method 2 works (minus textures) but there are no duplicate vertices, and therefore the normal orientation is not good for rendering. However, in this configuration, every single vertex is drawn in correct place. Notice the stride and vertex and index buffer structures are the same in both codes, its the size of the buffers that differs.

   ```
   #else
   std::vector<float> vertex_buffer;
   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < attrib.vertices.size(); i += 3, j += 2)
   {
       vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.vertices[i + 0]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.vertices[i + 1]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.vertices[i + 2]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.normals[i + 0]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.normals[i + 1]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(attrib.normals[i + 2]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(0);//attrib.texcoords[j + 0]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(0);//attrib.texcoords[j + 1]);
       vertex_buffer.push_back(0.0F);
   }

   std::vector<UINT> index_buffer;
   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < shapes[0].mesh.indices.size(); i += 3, j += 2)
   {
       index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i + 0].vertex_index);
       index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i + 1].vertex_index);
       index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i + 2].vertex_index);
       index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i + 0].normal_index);
       index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i + 1].normal_index);
       index_buffer.push_back(shapes[0].mesh.indices[i + 2].normal_index);
       index_buffer.push_back(0);
       index_buffer.push_back(0);
       index_buffer.push_back(0);
   }
   uint32_t vertexes_size = vertex_buffer.size() * sizeof(float);
   uint32_t indexes_size = index_buffer.size() * sizeof(uint32_t);
   int stride_bytes = 36;
   #endif
   ```
3. This is where I create buffers, its the same code for both methods

   ```
   //Set Vertex Buffer Array
   g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray = new SDKMESH_MESH;
   g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_VERTEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
   int t = g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0];
   g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0] = 0;
   D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertex_buf_desc;
   vertex_buf_desc.ByteWidth = vertexes_size;
   vertex_buf_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
   vertex_buf_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
   vertex_buf_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
   vertex_buf_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
   D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA init_vertex_data;
   init_vertex_data.pSysMem = &vertex_buffer[0];
   dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&vertex_buf_desc, &init_vertex_data, &g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].pVB11);
   g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].StrideBytes = stride_bytes;
   g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].SizeBytes = vertexes_size;

   //Set Index Buffer array
   g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer = 0;
   g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_INDEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
   g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].IndexType = IT_32BIT;
   D3D11_BUFFER_DESC index_buf_desc;
   index_buf_desc.ByteWidth = indexes_size;
   index_buf_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
   index_buf_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
   index_buf_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
   index_buf_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
   D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA init_index_data;
   init_index_data.pSysMem = &index_buffer[0];
   dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&index_buf_desc, &init_index_data, &g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].pIB11);
   g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].SizeBytes = indexes_size;

   //Set subset
   SDKMESH_SUBSET v_subset;
   v_subset.MaterialID = 0;
   v_subset.PrimitiveType = PT_TRIANGLE_LIST;
   v_subset.IndexCount = index_buffer.size();
   v_subset.VertexCount = vertex_buffer.size();
   v_subset.VertexStart = 0;
   v_subset.IndexStart = 0;
   g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets = new uint32_t;
   g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0] = 0;
   g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].NumSubsets = 1;
   g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray = new SDKMESH_SUBSET;
   g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0]] = v_subset;
   ```

Additional information:

1. I tried with lower poly count models and the issue is still there, so I am not hitting some limit of vertices.
2. Here are the sizes of the arrays

`attrib.vertices.size = 150201`

`attrib.normals.size = 173712`

`attrib.normals.size = 135956`

`shapes[0].mesh.indices.size() = 300978`

- In Method 1 in the above example

`temp_vertices.size() = 300978` (matches index size, so I'm not missing any vertices in `temp_vertices`)

`vertex_buffer.size() = index_buffer.size() = 2708802`

- In Method 2 in the above example

`vertex_buffer.size() = index_buffer.size() = 450603`

3. Here is the input layout

   ```
   // Create our vertex input layout
   const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
   {
       { "POSITION",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
       { "NORMAL",    0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
       { "TEXCOORD",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,    0, 24, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
   };
   ```
4. Here is the Vertex Shader

   ```
       cbuffer cbPerObject : register( b0 )
   {
       matrix      g_mWorldViewProjection  : packoffset( c0 );
       matrix      g_mWorld                : packoffset( c4 );
   };

   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Input / Output structures
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   struct VS_INPUT
   {
       float4 vPosition    : POSITION;
       float3 vNormal      : NORMAL;
       float2 vTexcoord    : TEXCOORD0;
   };

   struct VS_OUTPUT
   {
       float3 vNormal      : NORMAL;
       float2 vTexcoord    : TEXCOORD0;
       float4 vPosition    : SV_POSITION;
   };

   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // Vertex Shader
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   VS_OUTPUT VSMain( VS_INPUT Input )
   {
       VS_OUTPUT Output;

       Output.vPosition = mul( Input.vPosition, g_mWorldViewProjection );
       Output.vNormal = mul( Input.vNormal, (float3x3)g_mWorld );
       Output.vTexcoord = Input.vTexcoord;

       return Output;
   }
   ```
5. I realize there are inconsistencies between the input layout, the shader, and my vertex_buffer vector. Mainly, the input layout is 32 bytes, my buffer is 36 bytes with 3 bytes for texcoord, and the shader is 36 bytes, but the position is 4 bytes, and texcoords are 2 bytes.

The shader and initialization was from DXUT and I did not mess with those. It draws the supplied `Tiny.sdkmesh` model correctly, which incidentally has a stride of 32 bytes, matching that of input layout.

If somebody can help explain why the shader VS_INPUT differs from the input layout, it would greatly help as well.

Changing the vertex shader to math input layout resulted in compilation errors. Changing input layout to add an extra byte to `texcoord` did not really make a difference.

Note: I tried removing the `vertex_buffer.push_back(0.0F);` and `index_buffer.push_back(0);` from the end and changing `stride_bytes` to 32, but it was no longer drawing vertices correctly.

I've ran out of trial and error methods to test and looking for help figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

After dissecting the working tiny.sdkmesh file, I found what I was doing wrong.

The index is only 1 entry/byte per vertex (which is 32 bytes)

I tried it before, but not successfully, here is the working code:

Still looking for some explanation to help understand why the Input_Layout differs from Vertex Shader in number of bytes

```
    std::vector<float> vertex_buffer;
    std::vector<uint32_t> index_buffer;

    struct T_Vertex
    {
        float vX;
        float vY;
        float vZ;
        float nX;
        float nY;
        float nZ;
        float tX;
        float tY;

        uint32_t vIndex;
    };

    std::vector<T_Vertex> temp_vertices;
    size_t index_offset = 0;
    int ind = 0;
    for (size_t f = 0; f < shapes[0].mesh.num_face_vertices.size(); f++) {
        int fv = shapes[0].mesh.num_face_vertices[f];
        // Loop over vertices in the face.
        for (size_t v = 0; v < fv; v++) {

            // access to vertex
            tinyobj::index_t idx = shapes[0].mesh.indices[index_offset + v];
            if (idx.vertex_index < 0 || idx.normal_index < 0 || idx.texcoord_index < 0)
                continue;
            T_Vertex temp_vertex;
            temp_vertex.vX = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 0] : 0;
            temp_vertex.vY = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 1] : 0;
            temp_vertex.vZ = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.vertices[3 * idx.vertex_index + 2] : 0;
            temp_vertex.nX = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 0] : 0;
            temp_vertex.nY = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 1] : 0;
            temp_vertex.nZ = idx.normal_index > 0 ? attrib.normals[3 * idx.normal_index + 2] : 0;
            temp_vertex.tX = idx.texcoord_index > 0 ? attrib.texcoords[2 * idx.texcoord_index + 0] : 0;
            temp_vertex.tY = idx.texcoord_index > 0 ? attrib.texcoords[2 * idx.texcoord_index + 1] : 0;

            temp_vertices.push_back(temp_vertex);
            temp_vertex.vIndex = ++ind;
        }
        index_offset += fv;
    }

    for (auto& temp_vertex : temp_vertices)
    {
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vX);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vY);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vZ);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nX);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nY);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.nZ);
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.tX); //Set to 0 for no texture
        vertex_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.tY); //Set to 0 for no texture

        index_buffer.push_back(temp_vertex.vIndex);
    }

    uint32_t vertexes_size = vertex_buffer.size() * sizeof(float);
    uint32_t indexes_size = index_buffer.size() * sizeof(uint32_t);
    int stride_bytes = 32;
```